# How to move from text to text by keyboard in Powerpoint?

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

How do I move from text item to text item using the keyboard in Powerpoint? (Apologies for the Windows keyboard terminology in the following)

- <kbd>tab</kbd> just adds a tab, as does <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches application.
- <kbd>enter</kbd> adds a newline, as does <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> starts a presentation, as does <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I tried looking at http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/powerpoint/item/13dfdf52-4ce3-4ec5-aeff-5b49f8392aea, but couldn't find what I wanted.

Comment: If someone reasonably experienced in keyboard shortcuts could confirm that there's no better options, I'd accept either their or my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>windows</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> to indicate you've finished a piece of text and want to move on to the next section, possibly creating a new slide.

Use <kbd>esc</kbd> to escape from whatever you're editing, *then* use <kbd>tab</kbd> to move from text to text within a slide, and use <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> to move from slide to slide, and use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start editing a text.